# C# WPF Set Focus TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl and i want to set the focus on the firsttab on a Textbox.

I tried to use in Code:

```
 this.tabItemMerkmalAllgemein.Focus();
 this.textBoxMerkmalBezeichnung.Focus();
```

If the second tab was selected the first Tab will be selected after this but no Cursor at the Textbox is shown, so the Textbox focus dosen't work.

XAML TabControle:

```
<TabControl Width="359" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource EditDialogTabControl}" Name="tabControlMerkmalDetails" Margin="4,0,0,0">
                        <TabItem Header="Allgemein" Name="tabItemMerkmalAllgemein" GotFocus="tabItemMerkmalAllgemein_GotFocus">

…
 <Label      Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource EditDialogLabel}" Content="Bezeichnung"/>
               <TextBox x:Name="textBoxMerkmalBezeichnung"    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                  Style="{StaticResource EditDialogTextBox}" MaxWidth="300"
Text="{Binding Path=bezeichnung, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
TextChanged="textBoxMerkmalBezeichnung_TextChanged"      LostFocus="textBoxMerkmalBezeichnung_LostFocus" />
…
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem  Name="tabItemKostenpflichtig">
…
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your declaration of the `TabItem` to this:

```
<TabItem FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=textBoxMerkmalBezeichnung}" 
Header="Allgemein" Name="tabItemMerkmalAllgemein" GotFocus="tabItemMerkmalAllgemein_GotFocus">
```

The important part is the addition of the `FocusManager.FocusedElement` attached property.  You can find out more from the [FocusManager.FocusedElement Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.focusedelement.aspx) page at MSDN.